# How to make Webpack and Node work together?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was planning to use ES6 Modules on front-end so I did experiment on Webpack. However, I am having a hard time making the ff: work

1. Hot reload when there are changes in client-side
2. Hot reload when there are changes in server-side (before webpack, I'm using `nodemon .` and not have issues with it)
3. Losing debug/console.log info in terminal since it's printing the webpack status and nothing on the server e.g my custom 'Server running....' log.

The setup below I was trying to run via `npm start`. And everytime I make any change, I have to run `npm start` again

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "socket-io-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --watch && node --watch",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "*",
    "socket.io": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "public");
var DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "public/js/dist");

var config = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
    entry: {
      guest : path.join(SRC_DIR, "entry-guest.js"),
      authenticated : path.join(SRC_DIR, "entry-authenticated.js")
    },
    output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  modules: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "stage-2"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    https: false,
    contentBase: SRC_DIR,
    stats: 'errors-only',
    port: 3000
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**server.js**

```
//create server
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

console.log('here');

var server = require('http').createServer(app);

//prepare socket io, make it listen to server
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
console.log(`Server running *:${port}`);

//routing
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

//open a connection
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected:', connections.length);

  //...more codes here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your webpack config file you can try using the plugin "Hot Module Replacement"

Along side with your already implemented Nodemon you should have both the client and server reloading on changes.

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
         NODE_ENV: '"development"'
       }
   })
],
```

Here is an example webpack config utilizing HotModuleReplacement.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'index.jsx')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"'
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
            {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
        'file-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
    devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```